# Value classes / strict typing in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, type-alias, value-class

Is it possible to define value classes for strict types in TypeScript as it is done in Scala?

Type aliases seems to be ignored by TypeScript "compiler":

```
export type UserId = number;
export type CarId  = number;

const userId: UserId = 1

const findUser = (userId: UserId) => { ... }
findUser(userId) // OK

const findCar  = (carId: CarId) => { ... }
findCar(userId) // OK too! I would like to prevent such behavior
```

In Scala we can use value classes (besides strict typing it provides more advantages):

```scala
case class UserId(value: Int) extends AnyVal
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible in TypeScript. TS uses [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) (also called duck typing), which means that anything that looks enough like a given type, will be accepted as that type.

In your case, both `UserID` and `CarID` are structured as just numbers and can thus be used interchangeably.